# My default argument fails to work in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

**objective**: set a default message in my script to handle commits toward Bitbucket

***problem***: my console returns me an error

Following what i have seen in google I have try the following script:

```
commit_message=${1:"checkpoint commit"} 
git add .
git commit -m $commit_message
git push origin
```

As I have said, it returns me an error, reproduced here:

> nothing added to commit but untracked files present error: src refspec
>   handle does not match any. error: src refspec programmaticScrolling
>   does not match any. error: src refspec adjustment does not match any.
>   error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://bitbucket.org/yyyyyyy.git'

Comment: Why are you re-using `$1` at the end with your `git push`  are you formatting your commit message as a `refspec` parameter?

Comment: oups I have made a typo for the last line, I have edited my post :).

Answer (score 0):

It's a minor syntax issue.  In `bash`, and other POSIX compliant shells, when using a default value, the important separator character isn't the `:`, it's the `-` or `=`.

```
commit_message=${1:-"checkpoint commit"} 
git add .
git commit -m "$commit_message"
git push origin
```

Documentation for default values and alternate values can be found here:

- https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value

Comment: Need to double-quote `"$commit_message"` so that spaces in the message text are kept unchanged. I'd double-quote the usage of `"$1"` on the last line for the same reason, too (and actually for completeness in the first line's assignment).

Comment: This is not `bash`-specific, but has to do with the POSIX shell syntax for [parameter expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: It's possible the actual issue was unrelated to the syntax error in the default value assignment, and entirely do to try to use the commit message as a refspec parameter in the `git push origin` line.  I didn't notice that originally, but it does line up with the `refspec` related error message in the OP.

Comment: @TimKennedy That may well be a second issue, yes.  My `git`-foo is not strong enough to say anything constructive about it though.